# Issues running Spring application using Gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I downloaded the source code of a book am reading - Spring Security. I tried to run the code as described using the Gradle configuration (each project contains this Gradle config) below but I get error when I run it with `gradle tomcatRun` command at the prompt.

The gradle file is:

```
/*
 * Chapter 2 Calendar
 *
 * @author Mick Knutson
 */
buildscript {
    ext {}
    repositories {
//        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${dependencyManagementPluginVersion}"
        classpath "com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:${bmuschkoGradleTomcatPluginVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat"
apply plugin: "com.bmuschko.tomcat-base"

// Spring Security 4, for chapter 2, version 0
version = "4.2.1-SNAPSHOT"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom ("io.spring.platform:platform-bom:${springIoVersion}")
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Misc from Spring IO
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"

    // Spring Dependencies:
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-expression"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-tx"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test"

    // Spring Security Dependencies
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"

    compile "javax.servlet:jstl"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api"

    // Logging
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api"

    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl"
    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"

    compile "javax.validation:validation-api"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor"

    // Thymeleaf Spring
    compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf"
    compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4"

    // Joda time. TO be replaced with Java 8 Time
    compile "joda-time:joda-time"

    // Testing:
    testCompile "junit:junit"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core"
    testCompile "org.assertj:assertj-core"

    // Selenium / WebDriver
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support"

    // Gradle Tomcat plugin
    def tomcatVersion = "8.0.42"
    // FIXME: These versions are not found:
//    def tomcatVersion = "8.5.2"
//    def tomcatVersion = "9.0.0.M6"
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/exploded"
    with war
}

war {
    baseName = "calendar"
    archiveName = "${baseName}.war"
}

war.doLast {
    explodedWar.execute()
}

war.dependsOn explodedWar

tomcat {
    httpPort = 8080
    httpsPort = 8081
    enableSSL = true

    contextPath = "/"

    users {
        user {
            username = "admin"
            password = "admin"
            roles = ["developers", "admin"]
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\Spring Security 3rd Edition_Source_Code\JBCPCalendar\chapter02\chapter02.01-calendar>g
radle tomcatRun
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Task :chapter02:chapter02.01-calendar:tomcatRun

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standa
rd format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\user\Downloads\Spring Security 3rd Edition_Sour
ce_Code\JBCPCalendar\chapter02\chapter02.01-calendar\build\tmp\ssl\keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\user\Downlo
ads\Spring Security 3rd Edition_Source_Code\JBCPCalendar\chapter02\chapter02.01-calendar\build\tmp\ssl\keystor
e -deststoretype pkcs12".

A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardH
ost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webreso
urces.StandardRoot@40a58621]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
        at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1112)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory
.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamH
andlerFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFacto
ry.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:682
)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:665)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 10 more

> Task :chapter02:chapter02.01-calendar:tomcatRun FAILED
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:346)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$start$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.BaseTomcatServerImpl.start(BaseTomcatServerImpl.groovy:56)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.TomcatServer$start$9.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.startTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:359)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure2.do
Call(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:228)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure2.do
Call(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler.withJdkFileLogger(LoggingHandler.groovy:56)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler$withJdkFileLogger.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat(AbstractTomc
atRun.groovy:227)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure1.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:
220)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure1.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.withClasspath(TomcatThread
ContextClassLoader.groovy:30)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.ThreadContextClassLoader$withClasspath.call(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.start(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46
)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(D
efaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(D
efaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java
:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecuto
r.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTask
Executer.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTas
kExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecut
er.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectory
CreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.j
ava:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOu
tputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyEx
ecuter.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:
59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFil
esTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInp
utFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExec
uter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArt
ifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActions
Executer.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:
54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTask
Executer.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecut
er.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:
51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(D
efaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(D
efaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java
:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecuto
r.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.jav
a:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execut
e(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execut
e(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExec
utor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExec
utor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecut
or.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPl
anExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.j
ava:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:
63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:5
5)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardH
ost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':chapter02:chapter02.01-calendar:tomcatRun'.
> An error occurred starting the Tomcat server.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

In the error you can see multiple lines like:

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [St
andardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

I have been trying to find answers to get it run but no success.

### Note

The code am trying to get it run can be downloaded from their [github's](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Spring-Security-Third-Edition) page or from [here](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/29457), its free. Each chapter contains multiple independent projects. For instance **chapter 2** contains projects like **chapter02.01-calendar**, **chapter02.02-calendar** etc... You just go into the folder with your command line prompt and execute `gradle tomcatRun` as suggested on the book's [GitHub](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Spring-Security-Third-Edition) page

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same library versions that are specified in the book you are reading? Something may have changed if the book is older/newer than the version of spring/gradle you are using.

Comment: @ the gradle configuration is suppose to download all the libraries

Comment: I was able to get it to run on the first try. I went to the chapter root typed 'gradle wrapper' then waited and when it was done I typed './gradlew tomcatRun'. You may need to type './gradlew --build-cache clean' before tomcatRun or perhaps 'rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/ rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/daemon/' according to their readme (I was in this folder Chapter02/chapter02.01-calendar) (My gradle version is 4.2.1 perhaps you can install that as a wrapper using 'gradle wrapper --gradle-version=4.2.1')(also I'm on a Mac)